# How and where to use OAuth2RefreshtokensWebFilter?

Tags: jhipster, spring-oauth2

Hi I am new to both JHipster and Stackoverflow. I tried asking the same question on [Should OAuth2RefreshtokensWebFilter Be Used Some Where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294388/should-oauth2refreshtokenswebfilter-be-used-some-where) however, it was removed for some reason; hence, I am asking duplicate question.

Could you please share if there is an example of how to use this filter?

I have tried to add `OAuth2RefreshtokensWebFilter` to the method `SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)`  however  `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` is resolved as null in the filter.

Here is how I have added the filter

```
.and() //JHiPSTER Geneated
            .addFilterAfter(oAuth2RefreshTokensWebFilter, OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .oauth2Client(); //JHiPSTER Geneated
```

I am experimenting using Keycloak as SSO provider and the object is being resolved properly at `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` when tried to add it in the `aacouts` resource just for debugging. This proves that the Filter is called before the login, even after defining to invoke after login.

What is the correct way of adding this filter?

Comment: As to your initial comment: it was removed, because you posted it in a space reserved for answers. The comment you got suggested to do exactly what you did now: ask a new question. Please take the [tour], read up on [ask] and [answer] to get an idea on how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some one interested, we were able to use this with `BasicAuthenticationFilter.class`.

Below is the code as an example:

```
.and() //JHiPSTER Geneated
.addFilterAfter(oAuth2RefreshTokensWebFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
.oauth2Client(); //JHiPSTER Geneated
```

Didn't test the renew token part, yet